# Serialization using DataContract in WebApi. one of the type is turned into null

Tags: xml-serialization, datacontractserializer, datacontract, datamember

I am sending XML using PUT to WebAPI to add record to my database. Each class has the `[DataContract]` attribute and its fields have a `[DataMember]` attribute. The reason for this that we don't want to expose the actual type name to the enduser.

My class structure is as follows:

```
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember(Name = "CustomerId")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "CustomerType")]
    public CustomerTypeDTO CustomerTypeDto { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Orders")]
    public List<OrderDTO> Orders { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "CustomerType")]
public class CustomerTypeDTO
{
    [DataMember(Name = "CustomerTypeId")]
    public int CustomerTypeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "TypeCode")]
    public string TypeCode { get; set; }

}

[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "Order")]
public class OrderDTO
{
    [DataMember(Name = "OrderId")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "CustomerId")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

My Web Api controller accepts the XML as:

```
<ArrayOfCustomer>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerId>1</CustomerId>
        <Name>Customer A</Name>
        <CustomerType>
            <CustomerTypeId>1</CustomerTypeId>
            <TypeCode>Corporate</TypeCode>
        </CustomerType>
        <Orders>
            <Order>
                <OrderId>1</OrderId>
                <CustomerId>1</CustomerId>
                <Amount>100000.00</Amount>
            </Order>
        </Orders>
    </Customer>
</ArrayOfCustomer>
```

On receiving the XML, the `CustomerType` member is always null. I have spent lot of time to investigate the problem but no avail.

My controller method is as:

```
[RoutePrefix("customers")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("putcustomer")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(List<Customer> customers)
    {
        var orders = customers[0].Orders;
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Decorate your model with `XmlRoot`, `XmlAttribute` or `XmlMember` wherever appropriate. They specify how the XmlSerializer in 
WebApi serializes a class as an XML.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. I have decorated my model with the mentioned attributes, it is giving error "The request entity's media type 'application/xml' is not supported for this resource."

Comment: It could be because your application does not use a `XmlSerializer`. What serializers does your `webapi solution` use ? Also update your question to reflect your changes in the model.

Comment: I have used DataContractSeriailzer by adding reference of System.Runtime.Serialization.

Comment: Normally, `WebApi` supports `DataContractSerialization`, `XmlSerialization`, etc., Try to upload your solution in `github` and give me the link. May be I can help.

Comment: here is the code at GitHub : https://github.com/syedfasih/TestApi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62980/discussion-between-syed-fasih-and-now-he-who-must-not-be-named).

Comment: Did the answer below work out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell to the `WebApi` how to serialize the xml that you send along.

In your case, you are sending `Xml without any namespaces` and hence the binding is null.

Try sending your XML data like below:

```
<ArrayOfCustomer xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Customer>
   <CustomerId>20</CustomerId>
     <CustomerType>
       <CustomerTypeId>221</CustomerTypeId>
       <TypeCode>test</TypeCode>
     </CustomerType>
     <Name>test</Name>
   <Orders />
</Customer>
</ArrayOfCustomer>
```

I tested your solution with the above xml and it works :) Try reading more on how serialization is done in WebApi and its default serializers.

***Some suggestions (for WebApi) that you can checkout:***

1. Change your return type to `IHttpActionResult` instead of using `HttpResponse`. (See 2.0 release)
2. Write a `custom xml serializer` if you need to supply xml without any namespaces. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617471/adjust-mvc-4-webapi-xmlserializer-to-lose-the-namespace)

Comment: It worked with Custom Xml Serializer, Thanks alot dear!