# C# WEB-API and how to post xml as List

Tags: c#, rest

My C# web api:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("freeworks")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]List<AgadoFreeWork> value)
{
```

and I try to test POST as XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AgadoFreeWork>
    <IsPublished>true</IsPublished>
    ....
```

but I am getting back

```
{
Message: "The request is invalid."
ModelState: {
value: [1]
0:  "Error in line 1 position 23. Expecting element 'ArrayOfAgadoFreeWork' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Agado.Restful.Classes'.. Encountered 'Element' with name 'ArrayOfAgadoFreeWork', namespace ''. "
-
}-
}
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Answer (score 3):

You are sending an object of type "AgadoFreeWork" in your example, but your endpoint expects a list holding items of this type. As well I would define an array of type "AgadoFreeWork" for this endpoint, there is probably no need to use a List. Have a look at this post [Posting array of objects with MVC Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042853/posting-array-of-objects-with-mvc-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `namespace` in the **POST XML** that you are sending.  Add the namespace to your XML and it should work.

Like below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <ArrayOfAgadoFreeWork xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Also, you should be sending an array of AgadoFreeWork. Some thing like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ArrayOfAgadoFreeWork xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AgadoFreeWork>
      <IsPublished>true</IsPublished>
  </AgadoFreeWork>
</ArrayOfAgadoFreeWork>
```

If you don't want to send namespaces with the XML that you are sending, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617471/adjust-mvc-4-webapi-xmlserializer-to-lose-the-namespace)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried already with <ArrayOfAgadoFreeWork> but is the same, still the same message

Comment: @senzacionale: Did you try out the namespace thing, that I mentioned about ? See my updated answer..