# Remove all Namespaces using DataContractSerializer without Attributes or XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, namespaces, datacontractserializer

**The problem:**

I have created a WebApi and need to support XML.

The default DataContractSerializer generates namespaces like:

```
xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Vendor.App.Model.DeeperModel"
xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
```

I don't want to have these namespaces in my XML. Its very hard to work with them.

In my case I need to support XLST from FileMaker, which has problems with namespaces other XLS Parsers do not have.

**What I have found, but is not a duplicate for later statet reasons:**

I have read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617471/adjust-mvc-4-webapi-xmlserializer-to-lose-the-namespace), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590801/remove-namespace-in-xml-from-asp-net-web-api) and other locations in the web.

I only found this two advices:

- Use `[DataContract(Namespace = "")]`-Attribute
- Use XmlSerializer

  - by extending `XmlMediaTypeFormatter`
  - by setting `config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true`

**DataContract:**

DataContract Attribute does not work good for classes I have no control. I do not want to do this ugly hack:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
IThisIsNonesense<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
ThisIsNonesense<T> : List<T>, IThisIsNonesense<T>
{
    public ThisIsNonesense() : base() {}
}
```

**XmlSerializer:**

XmlSerializer is not very flexible. For example it does not support Interface. I make for example heavy use of `IEnumerable<T>`.

**My Question:**

How is it possible to remove all Namespaces by default, without making changes through the whole codebase? If it is not possible what would you advice?

Comment: I usually just parse the files myself using XDocument.

Comment: While this would work, this would be way to much overhead for me. I don't want to loose the benefits of serialization. Also my api methods should be available via JSON and any other format that will show up in the future. @jdweng

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7238007/5196274) which does use System.Xml.Linq but can be invoked to display in the console in one easy line:

```
Console.WriteLine(RemoveAllNamespaces(XElement.Parse(xml)).ToString());
```

However, you mention in your comment that you don't want to loose the benefits of serialization.  If one of those benefits is deserialization, then I'd advise against this - it will result in a SerializationException being thrown by DataContractSerializer.

Finally, it seems you're interested in making your API methods able to support multiple media types.  This is a [stated ability of ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-and-aspnet-web-api), so if you're already using .NET, this could be a good option.