# How to remove xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd from Web API XML serializer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xmlserializer

For some hours, I have battled with removing the default namespaces from the XML returned from serializing my independent objects (not MVC model) in ASP.NET Web Api. Sample codes for the application is:

Class Definition:

```
public class PaymentNotificationResponse
{

    [XmlArray("Payments")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Payment", typeof(PaymentResponse))]
    public PaymentResponse[] Payments { get; set; }
}
```

I then created a Web Api Controler that creates an object of the `PaymentNotificationResponse` based on some input, and then serialize the object to the requesting party. The Controller is listed below:

```
public class PaymentController : ApiController
{

    public PaymentNotificationResponse Post()
    {
        //Read request content (only available async), run the task to completion and pick the stream.
        var strmTask = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        while (strmTask.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) { }
        Stream strm = strmTask.Result;

        //Go back to the beginning of the stream, so that the data can be retrieved. Web Api reads it to the end.
        if (strm.CanSeek)
            strm.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //Read stream content and convert to string.
        byte[] arr = new byte[strm.Length];
        strm.Read(arr, 0, arr.Length);
        String str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arr);

        //Change the default serializer to XmlSerializer from DataContractSerializer, so that I don't get funny namespaces in properties.
        //Then set a new XmlSerializer for the object
        Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
        Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SetSerializer<PaymentNotificationResponse>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(PaymentNotificationResponse)));

        //Now call a function that would convert the string to the required object, which would then be serialized when the Web Api is invoked.
        return CreatePaymentNotificationFromString(str);
    }
}
```

Problem is, when I invoke the Api with valid string parameter, it returns an XML of this format (valid XML, but xmlns is not needed):

```
<PaymentNotificationResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Payments>
        <Payment>
            <PaymentLogId>8325</PaymentLogId>
            <Status>0</Status>
        </Payment>
    </Payments>
</PaymentNotificationResponse>
```

The system I'm sending this to doesn't need the `xmlns:xsi` and the `xmlns:xsd`. In fact, it returns an exception when it sees the namespaces.

I tried returning a string with XML tags, it just wrapped the response in a `<string></string>` and encoded all the < and >. So that was not an option.

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760262/xmlserializer-remove-unnecessary-xsi-and-xsd-namespaces/) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590801/remove-namespace-in-xml-from-asp-net-web-api). While the former is very detailed, it didn't solve my problem. It only just introduced one extra `xmlns` to the generated XML. I think it's because I didn't explicitly call `.Serialize()` function in the `XmlSerializer`.

I figured out a solution, and I thought I should share. So I would state it in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, I added a method to serialize the `PaymentNotificationResponse`and return an XML string, thus (I included this in the definition of `PaymentNotificationResponse`):

```
//I added this method after I tried serialize directly to no avail
    public String SerializeToXml()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        new XmlSerializer(typeof(PaymentNotificationResponse)).Serialize(ms, this, ns);
        XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);

        ms = (System.IO.MemoryStream)textWriter.BaseStream;

        return new UTF8Encoding().GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
```

I parsed the string to create an `XDocument`, then return the root element. This made me change the return type of the `Post()` method to `XElement`. The `Post()` listing would then be:

```
public XElement Post()
    {
        //...Same as it was in the question, just the last line that changed.

        var pnr = CreatePaymentNotificationFromString(str);
        return XDocument.Parse(pnr.SerializeToXml()).Root;
    }
```

That would make my response XML this:

```
<PaymentNotificationResponse>
    <Payments>
        <Payment>
            <PaymentLogId>8325</PaymentLogId>
            <Status>0</Status>
        </Payment>
    </Payments>
</PaymentNotificationResponse>
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: great solution, "return XDocument.Parse(pnr.SerializeToXml()).Root;" was the key.