# WebAPI XML formatter doesn't return all fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using WebApi2 to return XML **without the namespace.**  I would like to remove the i: below.

```
<PersonDetails 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FullJqueryForm.DTO">
    <FirstName i:nil="true" />
    <ID>0</ID>
    <LastName i:nil="true" />
    <MiddleName i:nil="true" />
    <Title i:nil="true" />
</PersonDetails>
```

using this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590801/remove-namespace-in-xml-from-asp-net-web-api), method 2

```
Added this to WebApiConfig.cs

config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

The trouble is that I when I just return a `new PersonDetails()` from the controller, JSON is returned fine. But if I set the

```
Accept application/xml
```

header and then send a get request I only get the ID field back. Json however returns all fields.

```
public class PersonDetails
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
   }
```

XML

```
<PersonDetails 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ID>0</ID> <!-- YO WebApi!! ... Where the rest of the fields at?? -->
</PersonDetails>
```

Json

```
{
    "ID": 0,
    "Title": null,
    "FirstName": null,
    "MiddleName": null,
    "LastName": null
}
```

Now

I have tried setting `Serializable` attribute on the PersonDetails Class , didn't work.

I 'd rather not use the DataContract attribute to remove the name space as I'd then have to put loads of DataMember attributes everywhere.

I think I'm missing something simple here. Why isn't the xml formatter returning all the fields?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to decorate those properties and set [`XmlElement.IsNullable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable(VS.85).aspx) to `true`:

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```