# Remove xmlns:i and xmlns from webapi

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, xml-deserialization

I have been asked to provide the following XML document from an http endpoint, exactly like:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <XMLFile xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<SalesOrders>
 ...
</SalesOrders>
```

However Web API spits out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XMLFile xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/White.Label.Ordering.Infrastructure.Data.Queries.Export">
    <SalesOrders>
        ...
    </SalesOrders>
```

I have google around and tried various fixes but to no avail, my model looks like

```
[DataContract]
public class XMLFile
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SalesOrder
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and my set up lools like this

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.WriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
        ...

    }
```

**How** do I remove `xmlns:i` and `xmlns` and replace with `xmlns:xsd` and `xmlns:xsi`?

I know this is a bad question as it shouldn't matter but my consuming client is barfing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590801/remove-namespace-in-xml-from-asp-net-web-api ?

Comment: No saw and tried that, wish it was

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need your XML to look exactly like something, then you might be better off with `XmlSerializer`. `DataContractSerializer` doesn't give you the same level of control as it's rather assumed you use it on both ends.

That said, I would imagine your consuming client is 'barfing' because the two instances are semantically different. The first has an empty default namespace, and the second has a default namespace of `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/White.Label.Ordering.Infrastructure.Data.Queries.Export`.

This should be the only thing you need to correct, which you can do by setting the namespace of the `DataContract`.

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
public class XMLFile
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace="")]
public class SalesOrder
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}
```

This will give you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XMLFile xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SalesOrders>
        ...
    </SalesOrders>
</XMLFile>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this on the XMLFile class, but did not add the Namesspace to all the underlying class namespaces. Will ask the client to try again. Thanks

Comment: Ah crap the consuming client is still barfing. Stupid antiquated xml systems, looks like I need to go down the XMLSerializer path

Comment: Went down the XMLSerializer instead, stupid means I can't use webapi anymore to future proof it for content type negotiation. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way we can remove xmlns:i  also from response message ?

Comment: @RanjithMurthy it's not something you can control. And it shouldn't matter. The only way I can think to remove it would be to parse the result again using e.g. `XDocument` and remove the attribute there.