# Can you ignore incoming namespaces in requests to a WebAPI method?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Coming to new to WebAPI and i am having a namespace issue

I have a POST method in my WebAPI that accepts an object as JSON or XML however the method is to be consumed by a BizTalk service which adds its own namespace to the xml.

```
<ns0:Person xmlns:ns0="http://Acme/Esb/DestinationSchemas/Person/v1.0">
  <WorkEmail>Someemail@acme.com</WorkEmail>
  <PersonId>10</PersonId>
  <UserName>Shouldhaveone</UserName>
</ns0:Person>
```

and my WebAPI Post method is defined as follows

```
<Person xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <PersonId>10</PersonId>
  <WorkEmail>Someemail@acme.com</WorkEmail>
  <UserName>Shouldhaveone</UserName>
</Person>
```

As you can see the namespaces are different and whenever the Post called the object is null. Can someone please advise me of the best approach to ignore the namespaces of incoming requests

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is to switch to using XmlSerializer in GlobalConfiguration:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Option 2 is to decorate your models with

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]
```

(and if you do so, you'd need to decorate the members with [DataMember] attributes).

original post 
[Remove namespace in XML from ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590801/remove-namespace-in-xml-from-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: tried that but the consumer was providing a namespace that we just didn't have any control over

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add XmlMediaFormatter to ignore namespaces

all thanks to Jan Jonas

http://blog.janjonas.net/2012-09-07/asp_net-mvc_4_rc-web-api-implementing-custom-xmlmediatypeformatter-ignore-xml-namespace